# PLSQL condition statement in trigger involving 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I've two tables purchases and customers, I need to update visits_made (number) in customers if time of purchase ptime (date) in purchases table is different from the already existing last_visit (date) in customers table.
Here is the trigger that I'm trying and I'm doing something terribly and shamefully wrong.

```
create or replace trigger update_visits_made
after insert on purchases
for each row
declare new_date purchases.ptime%type;

begin
  select ptime into new_date
    from purchases
  where purchases.ptime = :new.ptime;

  if new_date = customers.last_visit then
    new.last_visit=old.last_visit;
  else
    update customers 
      set visits_made=visits_made+1
    where purchases.ptime=:new.ptime;
  end if;
end;
/
show errors
```

Can anybody please tell me where I'm going wrong?

I get following errors
LINE/COL ERROR

---

> 10/15    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
>            following:
>            := . ( @ % ;
>
> 11/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE"
>
> 16/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: Please don't edit the question to correct the errors which others are advising you on. Otherwise it makes the question look pointless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scalar assignment in PL/SQL:

```
new.last_visit = old.last_visit;
```

Not only should this be done with `:=` but `new` and `old` should have colons before their names:

```
:new.last_visit := :old.last_visit;
```

Once you have fixed that problem, then the `update` will pose an issue:

```
update customers 
    set visits_made=visits_made+1
    where purchases.ptime = :new.ptime;
```

It is unclear to me what this is supposed to be doing, so I can't suggest anything, other than pointing out that `purchases` is not defined.

Comment: thank you, I need to update the visits_made column in customers by 1 if the purchases time ptime in purchases table is different from the present last_visit date in customers. I tried your suggestion and now I'm getting following error LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
10/1     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LAST_VISIT'
10/20    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.LAST_VISIT'
@Gordon Linoff

Comment: and the visits_made shouldn't change if customer is visiting more than once the same day @Gordon Kinoff

Answer (score 0):

```
I think somehow i get your requirement. Basically its a ticker which count the vists of user based on Login dates. I have written a snippet below which replicates the same scenario as mentioned Above. Let me know if this helps.

-- Table creation and insertion script
CREATE TABLE PURCHASES
(
P_ID NUMBER,
P_TIME DATE
);

INSERT INTO PURCHASES
SELECT LEVEL,SYSDATE+LEVEL FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
P_ID NUMBER,
P_VISITS NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
SELECT LEVEL,NULL FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;

-- Table creation and insertion script

--Trigger Script

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_purchase BEFORE
  INSERT ON purchases FOR EACH row 
  DECLARE 
  new_date purchases.p_time%type;
  BEGIN
  BEGIN
  SELECT A.P_TIME
    INTO new_date
    FROM
  (SELECT p_time,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY P_TIME DESC) RNK
    --    INTO new_date
  FROM purchases
  WHERE purchases.p_id = :new.p_id
  )a
WHERE A.RNK =1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN;
    END;
IF :NEW.P_TIME <> new_date THEN
  UPDATE customers
  SET P_VISITS        =NVL(P_VISITS,0)+1
  WHERE p_id=:new.p_id;
END IF;
END;

--Trigger Script


--Testing Script
INSERT INTO PURCHASES VALUES
(9,TO_DATE('12/11/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'));

--Testing Script
```